# JMeter-server freezes after starting test

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmeter, distributed-testing

I am doing `jmeter` distributed testing in AWS ec2 instance. My `jmeter` client machine(master) is in different AWS region on windows platform and `jmeter` server machine(slave) ) is in another region on linux platform. `JMeter` server is using public IP.

But when I remote start the jmeter server, it shows “starting the test on host xx.xx.xx.xx @…..” in linux terminal. After that nothing showing in the terminal and no results in jmeter client GUI. Even not hitting the application server(target server-hosted my own app). And it is taking more than 2 minutes to show that the test has started in linux terminal.

No errors showing in jmeter client GUI error log. Here is my GUI log..

```
   2016/03/16 05:03:59 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: xx.xx.xx.xx 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Wed Mar 16 05:04:00 UTC 2016 (1458104640482) 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
   2016/03/16 05:04:00 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
   2016/03/16 05:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent test to xx.xx.xx.xx basedir='.' 
   2016/03/16 05:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Sending properties {} 
   2016/03/16 05:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: sent run command to xx.xx.xx.xx 
   2016/03/16 05:06:09 INFO  - jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started
```

Please help to solve this....

Answer (score 0):

JMeter official distributed guide states that JMeter server and clients MUST be on same subnet. Have you checked if they share the same subnet addresses?

> all the clients are on the same subnet.
>
> the server is in the same subnet.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf

I personally created my JMeter master/slave machines in same region (using same security group). Subnet addresses were same. I did not faced any issue in scripts execution. Please check on network addresses of JMeter machines and ensure that they share same subnet.

Comment: But the document clearly says, "The server is in the same subnet, if 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x ip addresses are used. If the server doesn't use 192 or 10 ip address, there shouldn't be any problems". Means no problems when i use public IP. My jmeter server uses public IP.

Comment: Yep in case of public IP there should not be issue. May be you can look if you have properly defined remote_hosts in your jmeter.properties file? Also the command you are using to run script!  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html